# Pure CSS tabs - Prevent scroll to page top on tab change

Tags: html, css, tabs

My case completely described in title: when changing tabs, page scrolls to top and I have no idea how to prevent it...

```css
.ubdtabs {
  
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.ubdtabs li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.ubdtabs input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
.ubdtabs label {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 21px;

  
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1B6889 0%,#009DE0 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  
/*  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;*/
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.ubdtabs label:hover {
  background: #1B6889;
}
.ubdtabs .ubdtab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  
  left: 0;
  background: #b3d4fc;
}
.ubdtabs [id^="ubdtab"]:checked + label {
  
  
  background: #b3d4fc;
}
.ubdtabs [id^="ubdtab"]:checked ~ [id^="ubdtab-content"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<ul class="ubdtabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="ubdtabs" id="ubdtab1" checked />
        <label for="ubdtab1">first</label>
        <div id="ubdtab-content1" class="ubdtab-content">
        <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 
        </div>
    </li>
  
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="ubdtabs" id="ubdtab2" />
        <label for="ubdtab2">second</label>
        <div id="ubdtab-content2" class="ubdtab-content">
  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>  
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<br style="clear: both;" />
```

Or at Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwLPBQ

To reproduce:
1. Scroll page a little bit down
2. Click "second" tab
3. Page scrolls to top

Any Ideas?

Comment: I cant explain why its happening, but removing the top attribute from .ubdtabs input[type="radio"] appears to fix the problem

Comment: @BenBroadley  display:none; on the radio buttons also solves the problem.

Comment: @tkay it appears that the browser window focuses on the checkboxes when they are changed; setting top attribute to positive 9999px, scrolls the window to the bottom instead of the top.

Comment: @BenBroadley I've checked with positioning the checkbox at top:300px; When a window focuses on an element which is outside the viewport it automatically scrolls to that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the top & left styles and add `display:none;` to the radio input. While scrollbars are enabled if you focus on an input outside the viewport it scrolls to that element.

If you want to focus an element which is outside the viewport use this javascript code

```
var donotScroll = function(element) {
  var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
  element.focus();
  window.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```